# Is mathematical programming an analytical or numerical technique?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

Is linear programming, mixed-integer programming, integer programming, nonlinear programming, etc. numerical or analytical techniques?

I always thought they were numerical methods because you can't solve them without the aid of computers and number crushing (except very trivial cases). But wikipedia's page on operations research says it "is a discipline that deals with the application of advanced analytical methods to help make better decisions".

It would be great if someone could argue if it is analytical or numerical and why.

Thank you.